# How do you clean up jfloat when using jni

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I know that when my jni method comes to it end and I've been using jfloatArray I should then call :

`env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(vec,in,0);`

What about the `jfloat`,how to do the same with single primitives that aren't array types ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to clean up in cases where the `JNI` interface may have allocated memory or other resources. Basic types, like `jfloat` , are typedef's for **basic C++** **types** (usually, float), and are passed around by copy; when you declare a `jfloat`, it's just a floating point type on the stack, and disappears when you leave its scope.

Comment: Describing the use of the stack is a convenient model for understanding. But, there is no requirement for a compiler to use the stack for local variables or even for parameters (except when particular calling conventions are specified).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple **jfloat** (actually a typedefed' float) it will be removed by the stack, but if it is a jfloat* array that was allocated in the native side with **new** or **malloc** it needs to be cleaned with **delete[]** or **free**

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You don't have to. Since you ask you should understand this...

It would be nice to say that you **must** clean up only where the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#array_operations) say you have to clean up. Unfortunately, you have to infer or use other knowledge to tell. The docs are clear on which "release" functions are to be used in pairs with other functions. It turns out, that if there is a release function then you must use it. Such release functions are also among the only [functions that can be called while an exception is pending](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp815).

You **may** clean up local references; If you don't, JNI cleans them up automatically when the native method returns. There is a limit to the number of local references so you **should** clean up local references inside a loop if they are allocated inside it or in an (opaque) helper function if they are allocated by it.